# How do I call Wordpress get_stylesheet_directory_uri() in JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress

Firstly, I am hopeless with Javascript and have no idea about JSON.

I am currently building a website and incorporating **particles.js** into the design. I am at a loss, however, after searching for days, as to how I can call the get_stylesheet_directory_uri() function into the JSON configuration file.

I was able to figure out how to do it in the particles.js and particles-app.js by declaring a js variable in the header.php file globally, but as for JSON, I have no idea.

This is where I need to call this:

```
  "image": {
    "src": "sprites/blueBlur.png",
    "width": 100,
    "height": 100
  }
```

If I leave it as is, it points only to the root Wordpress file.

The whole JSON file is:

```
    {
  "particles": {
    "number": {
      "value": 43,
      "density": {
        "enable": true,
        "value_area": 800
      }
    },
    "color": {
      "value": "#00ffd8"
    },
    "shape": {
      "type": "image",
      "stroke": {
        "width": 0,
        "color": "#000"
      },
      "polygon": {
        "nb_sides": 6
      },
      "image": {
        "src": "sprites/blueBlur.png",
        "width": 100,
        "height": 100
      }
    },
    "opacity": {
      "value": 1,
      "random": true,
      "anim": {
        "enable": false,
        "speed": 1,
        "opacity_min": 0.1,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "size": {
      "value": 2,
      "random": false,
      "anim": {
        "enable": true,
        "speed": 10,
        "size_min": 40,
        "sync": false
      }
    },
    "line_linked": {
      "enable": false,
      "distance": 200,
      "color": "#ffffff",
      "opacity": 1,
      "width": 2
    },
    "move": {
      "enable": true,
      "speed": 1.9,
      "direction": "none",
      "random": true,
      "straight": false,
      "out_mode": "out",
      "bounce": false,
      "attract": {
        "enable": false,
        "rotateX": 600,
        "rotateY": 1200
      }
    }
  },
  "interactivity": {
    "detect_on": "canvas",
    "events": {
      "onhover": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "grab"
      },
      "onclick": {
        "enable": false,
        "mode": "push"
      },
      "resize": true
    },
    "modes": {
      "grab": {
        "distance": 400,
        "line_linked": {
          "opacity": 1
        }
      },
      "bubble": {
        "distance": 400,
        "size": 40,
        "duration": 2,
        "opacity": 8,
        "speed": 3
      },
      "repulse": {
        "distance": 200,
        "duration": 0.4
      },
      "push": {
        "particles_nb": 4
      },
      "remove": {
        "particles_nb": 2
      }
    }
  },
  "retina_detect": true
}
```

Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Since the url is assigned to global JS variable in header you can call/append it inside the JSON object like this.

```
var url = 'http://example.com/wp-content/themes/twentysixteen';

var json = {
  "image": {
    "src": url + "sprites/blueBlur.png",
    "width": 100,
    "height": 100
  }
};

console.log(json);
```

Comment: Hi @gvgvgvijayan, I have tried this but I am getting this error in Chrome DevTools `'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 350
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (particles.js?ver=4.7.5:1530)'` - I have updated the original post with the whole JSON file code.

Comment: @user3436334 check with firefox and report what will be the output.

Comment: Check the argument passed to `JSON.parse` is string and not JSON object. If so pass the value after stringify it.

Comment: I'm not getting any output from Firefox - and it's still not working.

Comment: Ok check the argument passed to `JSON.parse` as said in previous comment.

Comment: Sorry @gvgvgvijayan, I'm not sure what you're talking about. Never used JSON before and very very bad with JS

Answer (score 0):

You can use the direct url of your style sheet via using PHP.

Like

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; ?>/wp-content/themes/your_theme/style_directory/file.css
```

may be this will help you.